# Adding files to ZIP with PHP keeps failing

Tags: php, file, zip

For a automated download page, I want to quickly be able to add files that I'd like to share to a directory `files` so that a ZIP from all files in that folder will be created.

The directory looks as follows:

```
index.php
   |- files
         |- file1.jpg
         |- file2.jpg
         |- file3.jpg
         |- etc ...
```

Now, I have the following code in my `index.php`:

```
$dir = "files";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    if ($filename !== "." && $filename !== "..") {
        $files[] = $filename;
    }
}

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file,basename($file));
}
$zip->close();
```

When I `var_dump($files)` I get a list of files like "file1.jpg" etc, but when I `var_dump($zip)` I get:

```
object(ZipArchive)#1 (5) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["statusSys"]=> int(0) ["numFiles"]=> int(0) ["filename"]=> string(0) "" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Can anyone help me out where this goes wrong?
All files have 644 access and directories 755, I do not think that might be the problem.

Thank you

UPDATE: I found the problem with adding the files to the ZIP, but now I cannot figure out how to download the created zip, since it gets a 404 when trying to access the created zip. Updated piece of code:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $zip->addFile($dir . '/' . $file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you don't try use: exec(), to zip the files?

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: What would that help? I still need code to zip the file then, only with `exec()` that would be in an external program if I understand the php.net page correctly.